# How does a Dual-Port Wall Charger distribute Amperage output?

Tags: usb, amperage, output, adapter

I recently bought a Dual-Port Wall Charger that has a '3.4A total output'. Assuming the device(s) plugged in are individually capable of charging at 3.4A, is this specifying that a single device plugged in can charge at a maximum of 3.4A, while two devices plugged in will charge at 1.7A each? Or will each port always charge at 1.7A? Or will each port always charge at 3.4A?

Does 'total output' in the way described vary between manufacturer/device, or is 'total output' an industry standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the internal power supply is connected to both ports in parallel and has a current limit. If you try to draw more than 3.4 amps in total between the two ports (doesn't make any difference how...could be 3.4A on both ports, 2A on both ports, 3.4A on one and 1A on the other, etc.), the supply will go into current limit and either the voltage will drop or the supply will shut itself off.